# How do you set menuFormRepresentation for an NSToolbarItem in IB?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

How do you set the `menuFormRepresentation` for an `NSToolbarItem` in Interface Builder?

I was trying to transition from programmatically constructed window toolbars to ones created entirely in IB (with an ultimate goal of easier localization).

I'm also transitioning from image-based items to view-based item to support `NSButton` and `NSSegmentedControl` items.

My first step was to just modify the existing code to create view-based toolbar items instead of image items. That works just fine.

My next step was to rip out all of the code and use just IB (Xcode 9.2) to create the toolbar and toolbar items. Most of it works, but the NSButton items don't get enabled or disabled properly.

When I wrote the code, I had to create `NSMenuItem` (or `NSMenu`) objects for each toolbar item and use that to set the item's `menuFormRepresentation` property. According to the documentation "[Setting a Toolbar Item’s Representation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/SettingTBItemRep.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000722-BBCGFFHE)", if you don't do this a view-based item (a) won't get validated automatically and (b) will not appear in the text-only version of the toolbar or the overflow menu.

I've looked everywhere in IB I can think of, but there's no outlet, property, or attribute where you can set the item's `menuFormRepresentation` property. I've also tried dragging and dropping a menu item on the toolbar item; nothing happens.

The documentation for "[Creating a Toolbar in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Articles/ToolbarInIB.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008136-SW1)" doesn't make any mention of what to do about `menuFormRepresentation`, yet without it the item is functionally crippled.

Is this a huge hole in IB or am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to look into @IBInspectable, which allows you to set some attributes directly in the xib. Typically, they are user-defined attributes, but I *think* it'll work for this as well.

Comment: Thanks @theeagle, I will definitely check that out.